# Get Top 3 predicted classes from GaussianNB classifier python

Tags: python, naivebayes

I am trying to predict a class using GaussianNB, but I need to get top 3 predicted classes to create a custom score for the prediction.

My training data is x,y,class where given x and y it needs to predict the class

tests variable cointains (x,y) values and testclass contains class values.

```
Test is a list data set in following format
Index Type Size Value
0 tuple 2 (0.6424, 0.8325)
1 tuple 2 (0.8493, 0.7848) 
2 tuple 2 (0.791, 0.4191)

Test class data 
Index Type Size Value
0 str 1 1.274e+09
1 str 1 9.5047e+09
```

Code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


clf_pf = GaussianNB()
clf_pf.fit(train, trainclass)
print clf_pf.score(test,testclass)

ff = clf_pf.predict_proba(test)
```

How to get the top 3 predicted classes from above variable ff?

```
My ff data is like below
    0           1      2         3    4             5    6   7    8
0 1.80791e-05   0   0.00126251  0   6.38504e-256    0   0   0   0   
1 2.89477e-199  1.01093e-06 0   1.1056e-55  0   5.52213e-67 0   0
2 2.47755e-05   0   2.43499e-08 0   1.00392e-239    0   0   0   0
3 2.54941e-161  3.79815e-06 0   1.53516e-40 0   1.63465e-41 0   0
```

Comment: shape of `ff` should be `[n_samples, n_classes]`, so you can use `numpy.argsort`.

Comment: Can you add more information about the dataset, I think it may clarify the question. For example, what are the shapes of testclass?

Comment: Updated my post with data

Comment: Perfect. I just added an answer (check it now, since I got it wrong before; now it's working  as expected)

Comment: Maybe adding this information may help: `train.shape, trainclass.shape, test.shape, testclass.shape`, also, printing some rows of `testclass` may clarify help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, `ff` has `[n_samples, n_classes]`. Using [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) you will obtain, for each row, the predicted classes ordered by their probability in ascending order, obtaining again a matrix of shape `[n_samples, n_classes]`. You  then take the last three elements of all rows (`[:, -3:]`) and reverse their order (`[:, ::-1]`) to obtain the class with best probability first:

```
np.argsort(ff)[:, -3:][:, ::-1]
```

Note the `[:,` in the slicing just means "get all the rows".

Comment: I am getting results like below

143 4832 742

4573 2050 520

3390 3795 242

3342 4459 3816

which are not my classes data

Comment: I have updated my post explaining my ff data can you explain what that means?

Comment: `ff` has 1 row for each sample in `test` and one column for each class in `trainclass`. So, if you take the first row `ff[0, :]` or `ff[0]` you have 8 columns with the probability of each class:  `1.80791e-05   0   0.00126251  0   6.38504e-256    0   0   0   0` means that class `0` has probability `1.80791e-05`, class `1` probability `0` and so on. `ff[20, 5]` has the probability the classifier assigned to your sample `20` to be of class `5`. `sklearn` doesn't handle class names, `class 5` is the index of your actual class name, which you should hold somewhere else.

Comment: Can i know how sklearn is saving my class names?

Like the order in which the sklearn stores my classes?